# How to: Typescript instance fields to avoid undefined

Tags: typescript, constructor, undefined

I've created a couple of Typescript classes, but when i instance them i get undefined error when i try to use them

I've tried to instance my field into constructor, it works but i don't believe this is a good practice.

```
export class Organization { name: string; code: string;}

export class Partner {
  name: string;
  organization: Organization;
}

const p = new Partner();
p.Organization.name = "ORG"; <----'Can't set "name" of undefined'
```

```
export class Partner {
  name: string;
  organization: Organization;
  constructor(){
    this.organization = new Organization(); <--- is there other way?
  }
}

const p = new Partner()
p.Organization.name = "ORG" <--- it works already
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to initialize the member in the constructor.

You can just do it as part of the property declaration:

```
export class Partner {
  name: string;
  organization: Organization = new Organization();
}
```